# retrieving data from a multiple query seach in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have just started to use firebase in my android project and the problem i am facing that i want to retrieve data from firebase based on a multiple query search.

```
 Query query = firebase.orderByChild("sender").equalTo(senderEmail);
```

and i want something like

```
Query query = firebase.orderByChild("sender").equalTo(senderEmail).orderByChild("reciever").equalTo(receiverEmail");
```

but it throws an exception that you can not use multiple  `orderByChild` in a single query. Any help will be highly appreciated.
If this question has been asked before please refer me to the link

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: thank you @FrankvanPuffelen really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Firebase doesn't support ordering by multiple queries.

> Queries can only order by one key at a time. Calling orderByChild()
>   multiple times on the same query throws an error.

More [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html).

But real question is why are you doing ordering if you want just one element?